# Error message in terminal while using Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I open jupyter lab from anaconda-navigator. Though it works totally fine for me, but an error message keeps coming on my terminal.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shun/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 455, in _conda_info_processed
    processed_info = self._process_conda_info(info)
  File "/home/shun/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 566, in _process_conda_info
    processed_info = info.copy()
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I am working on:

Ubuntu 18.04

anaconda Command line client (version 1.7.2)

anaconda navigator (version 1.91.12)